# Cisco SA520 to Adtran 1234 no DHCP transfer

Tags: firewall, cisco, dhcp, networking

I am trying to set up a Cisco SA520 to run DHCP on my network. I have a vendor provided switch, the Adtran 1234, and it provides DHCP for our phone systems on VLAN 200. I do not have access to the Adtran, but the vendor gave me a IP on port 1 for WAN and said port 2 should be for the "trust" side should go.

I did setup a mini lab where, Adtran 1 went to SA520 WAN port, and SA520 trust 1 went to my laptop. Everything worked fine, I could ping and get internet using the DHCP scope I put on the SA520.

I then unplugged my computer from SA520 trust 1 and plugged it into Adtran 2. I plugged my computer into Adtran 23 and I dont get DHCP or even a link light. If I restart my machine, I get a brief link and then it dies once the machine boots. I have tried several ports on the Adtran and none seem to work. Different cables as well.

However, when I plug a phone into the Adtran, the phone boot immediately and shows link.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adtran 1234 is 10/100 and while all ports are set to auto, that was the issue. I solved this by setting the WAN port and trunk 1 on the SD520 to Full Duplex 100 and I got on once I set my MBP to Full Duplex 100.

I took it a step further, and didnt want to reconfigure all of my machines. So I tested auto on "trust" 1 for the SD520, set my computer back to auto, and I am still going strong. Even when one-wired off of the phone.